# returning data from both the tables link with foreign key without join operations. i want only single table data

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api2, sql-server-2014

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCab()
    {
        var Cablist = objentity.tbl_cabtype;
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, (new { success = true, message = "Cab Type List", Cablist}));
        return response;

    }
```

i am stuck with this, two table are linked with foreign key. its returning data from both the table i need only one table data. please me with this....

i am getting the data in json format.

{"success":true,"message":"Cab Type List","Cablist":[{"tbl_cab":[{"tbl_driver":{"tbl_cab":[],"tbl_driver_image":[{"id":1,"driver_id":1,"driver_image":"1driver.jpg","driver_drivingliscence_image":"1off.jpg"}],"driver_id":1,"FullName":"balwant","Address":"greator noida","Location":"Sector 18, Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India","Lattitude":28.59091,"Longitude":77.31728,"Email":"balwant@gmail.com","Password":"12345","Mobile":9876543210,"created_date":"2016-08-04T17:24:33.477","updated_time":null},"Id":1,"Type":1,"Color":"White","Name":"Suzuki","RegNo":null,"driver_id":1,"created_time":"2016-08-04T17:24:34.47","updated_time":"2016-08-04T17:24:52.887"},{"tbl_driver":{"tbl_cab":[],"tbl_driver_image":[{"id":2,"driver_id":2,"driver_image":"2download1.jpg","driver_drivingliscence_image":"2on.jpg"}],"driver_id":2,"FullName":"Richa Gupta","Address":"C/O Munnalal Kailash Chand","Location":"Mayur Vihar Phase II, New Delhi, Delhi, India","Lattitude":28.61696,"Longitude":77.30085,"Email":"richa@gmail.com","Password":"12345","Mobile":9009634289,"created_date":"2016-08-04T17:27:06.083","updated_time":null},"Id":2,"Type":1,"Color":"Black","Name":"Jaquar","RegNo":"111234","driver_id":2,"created_time":"2016-08-04T17:27:06.873","updated_time":"2016-08-04T17:27:34.88"}],"Id":1,"CabName":"Mini","BasicCost":50.0000,"PerKmCost":8.0000,"created_date":"2016-08-04T17:22:00","updated_date":null},{"tbl_cab":[],"Id":2,"CabName":"Prime","BasicCost":80.0000,"PerKmCost":10.0000,"created_date":"2016-08-04T17:22:00","updated_date":null}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a list of anonymous objects:

```
 var listAnonymousObjects= Cablist.Select(c => new {<choose fieldname>=c.<field from db>,<choose fieldname2>=c.<field from db2> });
```

for example

```
var listAnonymousObjects= Cablist.Select(c => new {<id=c.Id,cabName=c.CabName });
```

**EDIT using class**

```
public class ResponseCab()
{
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public string CabName{get;set;}
}

    List<ResponseCab> cabs=Cablist.Select(c => 
new ResponseCab{Id=c.Id,CabName=c.CabName });
```

Comment: is there any other way to get data other than anonymous object.  @jeroen Dop

Comment: Sure, you can create a class with the properties you need.

Comment: Thanks @jeroen Dop